# How to prevent Router from accessing routed without valid id?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, router

In my my **App.js** file I used this **Switch** logic:

```
              <Switch>
                <Route path='/' exact component={Dashboard}/>
                <Route path='/question/:id' exact component={QPage}/>
                <Route path='/new' exact component={CreateQ}/>
                <Route path='/leaderboard' exact component={Leaderboard}/>
                <Route component={Error}/> 
              </Switch>
```

The code above works as expected. My only problem is, when the Router accesses */question/:id* and therefore renders the **QPage** component. Then, React throws an error of undefinded because inside of the **QPage** component, elements try to access the id and other props (which they take out of the url).
How can I prevent the Router from accessing routes with invalid ids?

Comment: You can't, how do you know they're invalid? Deal with that *on the page*.

Comment: I have a database running in the background. When I access the QPage component via the UI, a valid id is passed, because the question existst. My problem is just when I type a different id in the url that doesn't exist. But you are probably right. It looks likes I have to deal with the invalid id inside the component. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind, both relying on history package:

1. wrap the Qpage component in an Error Boundaries class, and call history.goBack() within componentDidCatch method https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html
2. Within Qpage's componentDidMount, call history.goBack() if API fails to return a question. Also, conditionally render the return around the state property you store the API result in.

```
{!this.state.property? <div/> : <div> . . . </div>}
```

Make sure to use history version 4.10.1 if React-Router-DOM is 5.2.0

history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import {Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import history from './history.js'

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={history}>
        <App />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Qpage or Error Boundaries

```
import history from './history'
```